# Switch keyboard type in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a textfield to enter search terms, plus a segmented control to indicate what database table should be searched:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    enum SearchMode: Int {
        case searchInNumbers, searchInAlphabet
    }
    @State private var mode = SearchMode.searchInNumbers
    @State private var searchString = ""
    private var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType {
        if self.mode == .searchInNumbers {
            NSLog("Setting keyboard to numbersAndPunctuation")
            return .numbersAndPunctuation
        } else {
            NSLog("Setting keyboard to default")
            return .default
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search string", text: self.$searchString)
                .keyboardType(self.keyboardType)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            Picker("Search in", selection: self.makePickerBinding()) {
                Text("numbers").tag(0)
                Text("alphabet").tag(1)
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }.padding(20)
    }
        
    private func makePickerBinding() -> Binding<Int> {
        Binding<Int>(
            get: {
                return self.mode.rawValue
            },
            set: { tag in
                self.mode = SearchMode.init(rawValue: tag)!
            }
        )
    }
}
```

The keyboard style should be the right one for the database table we search. This works, except when the keyboard is already up.

Meaning, when the user first taps the textfield, and then changes the segmented control, the keyboard type does not change.

I don't want to fix it with yet another wrapped UITextField. Can it be fixed in SwiftUI?

Comment: I have this same issue. @Bart did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I never found a satisfying solution...

Comment: I found this workaround may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70937864/1907538