# Reload TextField keyboard in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I am trying to change the keyboard type of a single `TextField` dynamically. That is, I have something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @Binding var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
  @State var searchText = ""

  var body: some View {
    TextField("placeholder", text: $searchText).keyboardType(keyboardType)
  }
}
```

Now, dynamically, I would like the keyboard to change from one keyboard style to the other, depending on what `keyboardType` is. However, what I've found is that `keyboardType` changes, but the soft keyboard doesn't. Rather, the keyboard stays the same, and only after I dismiss the keyboard and bring it back up, does it show something different.

I see that there is a [way to wrap `UITextField`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66397828/emoji-keyboard-swiftui) so that the keyboard updates dynamically. But I was wondering/hoping there'd be a way to do this in SwiftUI. Perhaps there's a way to access `UITextView`'s `reloadInputViews()` method? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@FocusState` – disable focus, change the keyboard, then focus again:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var mykeyboard = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    @FocusState var focus: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Divider()
            HStack {
                TextField("placeholder", text: $searchText)
                    .keyboardType(mykeyboard)
                    .focused($focus)
                
                Button("Submit") {
                    focus = false
                }
            }
            Divider()
            
            HStack {
                Button("Numbers") {
                    focus = false
                    mykeyboard = .numberPad
                    focus = true
                }
                Button("EMail") {
                    focus = false
                    mykeyboard = .emailAddress
                    focus = true
                }.padding()
                Button("Alphabet") {
                    focus = false
                    mykeyboard = .alphabet
                    focus = true
                }
            }

        }
        .padding()
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
}
```